# Users forced to log into Sitecore to go to home page

Tags: login

I've encountered an oddity related to preview/edit mode that could totally be by design, but is really annoying some of the user base (including myself).

When a user logs into Sitecore and then opens a page in Preview or Edit mode, then opens the home page of the site without any query strings (i.e. http://my.site.com), the home page is displayed but with the Sitecore navigation. This is expected (not the problem). However, when the user then logs out of Sitecore (or is kicked out due to inactivity), and then tries to go to the home page again, the Sitecore login screen comes up with the URL `/sitecore/login?returnUrl=%2F`, and they can't access the home page, unless they log into Sitecore or clear their cookies.

Is this expected functionality, and is there anything that can be done to just show the home page without any Sitecore stuff if they aren't logged in? Seems like Sitecore creates a cookie when the user previews a page and then that causes issues later on.

Comment: I noticed this when I had the cookie domain set to the same across all environments. Try changing it to be unique per environment.

Comment: @MarkGibbons how would one do that?

Comment: @Paul - You could also use incognito window or the like (for example chrome - ctrl+shift+n) and it should take care of it without having to clear cookies. Hope this helps.